# How do I plot 3 (x,y,value) on a Histogram3D[] function?

Tags: histograms

I have been trying to plot data using the Histogram3D function but I've had no luck, in excel I have  x, y and a value I want to plot for each pair, do I have to save this as a data file first? I have tried the syntax Histogram3D[{x,y,value},...] but this isn't in the right form.. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that what you want is really a histogram? `{x,y,value}` suggests `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Yes this has the kind of input I want, but I wanted it to be discrete bars rather than a mesh.. I guess there's a way to convert it into bars? I will look now

Comment: Try `Graphics3D` + `Cuboids` :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One out of many ways to do this:

```
lst = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2}};
```

Append 1 to each data point to get a data set that `BubbleChart3D` accepts:

```
bclst = {##, 1} & @@@ lst 
(* {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 1}} *)
```

Define a custom `ChartElementFunction` to produce `Cuboid` primitives:

```
ceF[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, v_,  meta_] :=
    {Cuboid[{xmin, ymin, 0.}, {xmax, ymax, (zmax + zmin)/2}]};
```

Use `BubbleChart3D` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
BubbleChart3D[bclst, ChartStyle -> 63, ChartElementFunction ->ceF]
```

[image]